# WorkFusion RPA Express Keyboard - Keystrokes action

Tags: rpa, workfusion

Using a `Keyboard - Keystrokes` action under RPA recorder, with the `Key combination` option, I want to capture the **Enter/Return** keystroke.

However,  as the dialogue box to capture the keystroke opens, it sets focus on `Save` button.

Hitting the Enter/Return key executes the save action instead of capturing the keystroke first!

Any suggestions?

[image: The Keystrokes properties]

[image: The dialog to capture keystroke]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dialog automatically closes, but the ENTER key is captured.

You can verify it by viewing the action details.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the Details empty field first and after that press enter you have to see the result in the Action Flow (central window)

[image]